# "MATLAB: corrupted double-linked list"

Tags: matlab, slurm

I recently started getting the error

```
MATLAB: corrupted double-linked list
```

about 90% of the time when running a moderately complex matlab model on a supercomputing cluster.

The model runs fine on my laptop [about 15 hours for a run, cluster is used for parameter sweeps], and has done for nearly 2 years.

The only difference in recent runs is that the output is more verbose and creates a large array that wasn't there previously (1.5 Gb).

The general pattern for this array is that it is a 3D array, built from saving 2D slices of the model each timestep.  The array is initialised outside of the timestepping loop, and slices are overwritten as the model progresses

```
%** init
big_array = zeros(a,b,c)

%** Loop
for i=1:c
    %%%% DO MODEL %%%%

    %** Save to array
    big_array(:,:,i) = modelSnapshot';
end
```

I have checked that the indexing of this array is correct (ie. `big_array(:,:,i) = modelSnapshot'` has the correct dimensions / size)

Does anyone have any experience with this error and can point to solutions?

The only relevant results I can see on google are for matlabs' mex-file stuff, which is not active in my model

(crashes are on matlab 2016a, laptop runs 2014a)

Comment: This sounds like an internal MATLAB bug. I would send it (together with the stack trace and other information that is dumped in a file in your home directory when MATLAB crashes) to the MathWorks support: https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports or https://www.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/create.html

Comment: what if you just try to do: `a= modelSnapshot'; ` does that work?

Comment: Good question. Yes, `a=modelSnapshot'` does work.  I use such commands repeatedly to save the current state of the model (and transfer it to subroutines that advance the physics of the model).